# Angular Directive that wraps host content with a component

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'd like to figure out how to code up the following scenario:

app.component.html:

```
<div *appSlideOutDir>Hey there!</div>
```

The directive code is this:

```
export class SlideOutDirDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const slideOutComponent =
      this.viewContainer.createComponent<SlideInComponent>(SlideInComponent);
    slideOutComponent.instance.viewContainer.clear();
    slideOutComponent.instance.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
      this.templateRef
    );
  }
}
```

The SlideOutComponent code is this:

```
export class SlideInComponent {
  constructor(public viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {}
```

Its template is this:

```
<div [class.slide-in]="show">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

This SlideOutComponent was originally used as a component you can wrap around anything and make it a slide-out snackbar (like in material) type of thing. However, I wanted to reuse it and use it in a directive to achieve the same thing...

However, the current code does NOT inject the original contents of `Hey there!` INSIDE the SlideOutComponent, but next to it as a sibling:

```
<app-slide-in>...</app-slide-in>
<div>Hey there!</div>
```

How do I get the `Hey there!` body of the original tag with the directive appear INSIDE the `<app-slide-in>`?

Comment: I came on Stack Overflow today to ask a similar question. I didn't even get this far, the only examples I found were how to create an opposite of *ngIf or showing components after a delay, basically either showing or not showing, too basic.

Comment: when you use "ng-content" in a **component** (not in a directive) you should put the "content" inside the tags `<app-slide-in>..HERE..</app-slide-in>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research on this, I have the answer for you.

Change your `SlideOutComponent` to accept a `templateRef` as input.

```
@Input() controlTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Then, in HTML, change `ng-content` to this:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="controlTemplate">
</ng-container>
```

Finally, change:

```
slideOutComponent.instance.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
  this.templateRef
);
```

to:

```
slideOutComponent.instance.controlTemplate = this.templateRef;
```

This approach worked for me - I was able to wrap any component with a label.

Comment: Excellent idea! It does require me to change the code of the SlideOutComponent which will no longer allow it to be used as a standalone component, but I guess I could just add some logic to it to behave as either or. Thanks!